# How can we use Google Play Service for back-end server validation?

Tags: php, android, google-api-java-client, google-oauth

I was following these articles: [Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) and [Stopping Vampires using License Verification Library (from 24:57 to 25:34)](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/evading-pirates-and-stopping-vampires-using-license-verification-library-in-app-billing-and-app-engine.html) to implement an In-App Purchase verification system for our Android apps.

I am a bit confused about how this works end-to-end and what we can assume about the generated token from calling [GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html#obtain) with the first email address found--when AccountManager returns more than one account. My questions are as follows:

1. Should we assume that any e-mail address used by the user to buy our
   app will generate the same token (i.e., same user + app ==> same
   token)?
2. If the answer to question 1 is no, is there a way to launch in-app
   purchase for a particular account/email?
3. It looks like Google is picking the first e-mail address returned by
   AccountManager for its in-app purchase dialog. Can we assume that
   this won't be changed by the user after in-app purchase dialog is
   launched? How do we find out if this changed after the in-app
   purchase returns?
4. What should we store in our database to identify this user? Is email
   address and/or token allowed? When does the token expire?
5. The java-client library looks very promising and powerful at first
   read. But, a number of things remains confusing. Is there an article
   that describes the end-to-end scenario--from an app initiating a
   call to a back-end server through launching the in-app purchase
   dialog, getting the result and closing with commits on the server?
6. What articles are the most useful for accomplishing this on Android?

The main issue we are trying to solve is to to get the full picture.

We've gotten the idea that we can avoid requiring userid/password by using the java client features and using tokens. We have registers our project (both the web app and android app on the same project) per the instructions for Google API Console. We have the php java-client for Google Play Service on our back-end server. We got our Android app to generate a token using the first email address and then call the in-app purchase dialog and handle the user response at the end of the dialog. We've got the parts. Now, we need to glue everything together. We are at the point of integrating with the back-end server. E.g., What is Redirect URi supposed to point to in our server? We've got a php url that we do http post messages to for our server app. We've included the code example for Google API client example--with client-id, secret, simple api key, etc. filled in--as an include to our php. But, what should we put in the redirect uri (we are missing a usage instruction for the example code)?

Also, we want to avoid having the e-mail used for the in-app purchase be different from what we log on our server database as the address the user used to buy our app; if the address is the correct thing to track, we want it to be the same as what was used for the purchase. This could be frustrating for our user if we make this mistake and prevent them from the features they paid for. We don't want to make this mistake and need some clarification on how Google Play Service works. If we initiated the server part of the workflow to get app Nonce / Payload / Credentials for the first e-mail address on the Android device, we would want that address to be used throughout the workflow. If the user changed this along the line, we want to be aware of this and gracefully recover. So far the articles have been helpful but incomplete. Any insight/suggestion is appreciated.